# How convert OSM relation to GeoJSON with LineString?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

I want to get the data for a relation from the overpass turbo API, convert it to GeoJSON and get the LineString. What script/library should I use? I am using the query below to get the data.

```
[out:json][timeout:300];
(
relation(19763);
 <;
);
out geom;
```

I have tried using [osmtogejosn.js](https://tyrasd.github.io/osmtogeojson/) but it doesn't return the same result as the overpass-turbo.eu export function.

Comment: OSM data consists of three basic [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) (nodes, ways and relations) and [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag). There are no LineStrings or MultiLineStrings in OSM, so you must be talking about a specific library or application.

Comment: I meant GeoJSON. I have clarified the question.

Comment: Weird that you get a different output. overpass-turbo uses https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson as far as I know.